# How to "analyze" a SQL query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure if I used the right term in my question.

I am creating a prototype, which allows users to type in a raw SQL query, which will query the backend DB. I want to also make sure that users only apply SQl to the tables that they are allowed to.

So when a user types in something like `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id > 10`, I feel like I need to

- Analyze the query to make sure that the tables are ok - in this case "t1"
- They cannot access any other admin-type tables. For example, I don't want them to access "information_schema (i.e. for Postgres)"

What do you think the best strategy would be for this?

FYI, I'm NodeJS, so the primary programming language would be Javascript.

Would I need to "parse" the query to make sure that the tables being accessed by the query are ok?

Answer (score 2):

It's extremely hard to make this secure. Event if you are trying to be smart and check for every "possible" aspect. There is also *dynamic SQL*. And all kinds of ways to obfuscate code.

I wouldn't let the world run any query with more permissions than they should have.

If at all, I would create a user with restricted privileges, so that he can only do what he's allowed to in the first place. Also be aware that some database objects are visible to `public` by default, some tables in the [system catalog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalogs.html) like `pg_class` for instance ...

Answer (score 1):

> What do you think the best strategy would be for this?

No to do it, frankly. Letting arbitrary remote users run arbitrary SQL with black-list or filtering based access control is pretty much guaranteed to result in compromise.

If at all possible, *generate the SQL yourself* based on the user's specifications of what they want to do. They might tell your software using a graphical query builder, a domain-specific language, or even your own attempt at an SQL dialect. The idea is that however you do it, *your program* builds the SQL from fully validated inputs, be they parsed input text or something else.

If you really must attempt to try to check user-written SQL statements, create a dedicated `ROLE` in the database with extremely limited rights. `REVOKE` access by `PUBLIC` to the `information_schema` and as much of `pg_catalog` as you can safely revoke. You'll probably need to `GRANT` it back to a group for non-restricted users to be members of. Be aware that some database drivers expect and require access to parts of the `pg_catalog`.

`GRANT` only the most limited possible rights to the table(s) of interest.

You could try doing SQL filtering as an additional sanity check, but you should assume the user can get access to everything their underlying user account can access. There are all sorts of ways to obfuscate SQL to get around text-based filtering.

Appropriate use of `SECURITY BARRIER` views (added in PostgreSQL 9.2) may help you further isolate the restricted rights users.

You could also use a `ProcessUtility_hook` written in C and installed in the back-end database to limit which users can run which commands at a very low level. This requires signficant coding skills and will only work in PostgreSQL 9.1 or newer. It doesn't affect regular `SELECT` and DML commands, only DDL and utility commands.

Finally, look into SEPostgreSQL, which adds strong mandatory access controls but requires even more expertise to use.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you ensure the query doesn't access incorrect tables by restricting (not granting) access for the user id that runs the query.  For a reporting purposes, grant select access to the table that are being reported on.

More importantly would be to examine the query for SQL injection, although if you only provide select access to a limited number of tables this is less of a problem than if they can create, update, or delete data.  Look for tools which help prevent SQL injection.